# Ошибка в Python local variable 'Line' referenced before assignment Python

Tags: python

Здраствуйте, у меня ошибка в коде:**local variable 'Line' referenced before assignment**
Где тут ошибка? Вот код

```
Line = 0
def func():
    Line = Line * 10
    print(Line)
func()
```

Comment: Если вы хотите изменить глобальную переменную, то в функции это нужно явно объявить: `global Line`

Answer (score 1):

У вас `Line` глобальная и тут разом использование ее значения и присваивание к ней.

Пометьте ее как глобальную:

```
Line = 0
def func():
    global Line
    Line = Line * 10
    print(Line)
func()
print(Line)
# 0
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: @ИмяФамилия, отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как принятый :)